# Predict mutiple y's with a set of features

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have the following sample set (obviously the real one is bigger but just for reproducing purposes). The dataset contains certain features (first three columns)
and two y's

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, "Tree", "Flower"], [1,1,0,'Tree','Water'], [0,1,0,'Tree','NA'], [2,1,0,'Water','Wood'], [1,1,0,'Flower','NA'], [1,1,1,'Tree','Flower'], [2,2,0,'Flower','NA'] ], columns=('feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'outcome1', 'outcome2'))
```

What I would like to do now is predict the different y's. Obviously I can create a test- and training set, distinguish the features and labels and then create a decision tree like this:

```
my_tree_one = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
my_tree_one = my_tree_one.fit(train_features, train_outcome)
my_dt_prediction = my_tree_one.predict(test_features)
```

However this would only give me one y. And I am looking for (possibly multiple) y's.

I am looking for a way to predict what are the chances for a particular tag considering the nature of the features. And then the tags with a value above a certain threshold should be shown. So if i have new data with feature 0,1,2 and set the threshold to 50% the outcome should for example be:

- 60% chance for tag "Tree"
- 55% change for tag "Water"

Does anybody have feedback on how I can get the output I am looking for?

Comment: Is there a difference between having "Tree" as the first or second tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is one of multi-label classification, which is naturally harder than simple classification.

There are several ways to solve it in scikit learn, one of which is to use a oneVSall regime with their OneVsRestClassifier like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, "Tree", "Flower"], [1,1,0,'Tree','Water'], [0,1,0,'Tree','NA'], [2,1,0,'Water','Wood'], [1,1,0,'Flower','NA'], [1,1,1,'Tree','Flower'], [2,2,0,'Flower','NA'] ], columns=('feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'outcome1', 'outcome2'))

# Binarize your classes
outcomes = zip(list(df['outcome1']), list(df['outcome2']))
MLB = MultiLabelBinarizer()
Y = MLB.fit_transform(outcomes)

# Extract your data
X = df[['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']]

# Define base classifier and meta-classifier
my_tree_one = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(my_tree_one)

# Train your classifier and output your predictions
clf.fit(X, Y)
predictions = clf.predict(X)  # predict on a new X
print MLB.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

---

If you want to use a different threshold for the final classification you can use `predict_proba` instead of `predict` and do the final classification yourself, like this:

```
threshold = 0.6
predictions = []

probabilities = clf.predict_proba(X)
for probability_row in probabilities:
    predictions.append([1 if p > threshold else 0 for p in probability_row])
predictions = np.asarray(predictions)
```

Comment: many thanks for elaborated answer! Would you also know how to put a threshold. So that for example only tags with a probability of > 60% are shown?

Comment: @HenkStraten Added an example.

Comment: How to use `inverse_transform` on `predict_proba()` as it will return the array of all the labels for particular new text input as probability? And let say out of 500 total labels, i only want `3-5 labels` for new text input, how to pass that in `multilabel.inverse_transform()` to get the labels?